# How to Align images one over another in android?

Tags: android

I want to align images one over another ie like collage. The images are from Gridview.The image should overlap one over other.plz any one help me to solve this.When clicking those images it should expand .. pls provide me some source code to solve this or provide some similar example

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried the `FrameLayout`?

Answer (score 2):

Have u ever thought to use `9-patch` image.On the click of the image u can just give the `Patch Scale`.And to overlap image over an image its better to use FrameLayout rather than The GridView.